# Как я могу сложить число с генерированным числом?

Tags: python

Привет,
Как я могу сложить число с генерированным числом которое состоит из 18 цифр?

```
 a = 100 + random.random(18)
```

Хочу получить резултат 100151215121512161518

Comment: Ок цифры... с Русским плохо

Comment: А, понял. Тогда ещё вопрос: вы хотите в результате получить число или строку? Случайное число всегда будет из 18 цифр, т.е. от 100000000000000000 до 999999999999999999? Или от 1 до 18 цифр, т.е. от 0 до  999999999999999999?

Comment: Мне надо 100 + число каторое состоит из 18 цифр

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/tQSJMm

```
from random import randint

a = int("100" + str(randint(1e18, 1e19-1)))
print(a)

a = int(100e19) + randint(1e18, 1e19-1)
print(a)
```

Comment: random() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: Я предположил, что твой код работает, но неверно. Раз это не так, попробуй использовать изложенные в ответе идеи на правильном коде. Либо воспользуйся другим ответом.

Comment: @alex вы же сами в вопросе написали `random.random(18)`, а теперь это у вас не работает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, он наугад написал псевдокод. А когда его восприняли как рабочий код и немного дописали в соответствии с минимальными представлениями о питоне, он решил сказать, что это совсем не работало...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я всё-таки исправил.

Comment: @alex, исправил.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Не уверен, что ОП понял разницу между первым и вторым способом.

Comment: Хотел было удивиться, что число длиной 21 знак входит в 4 байта, но оказалось, что в python 3 размер int не ограничен. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: @NickVolynkin этот код работает и на v2: 
`type(int(100e19) + randint(1e18, 1e19-1))
<type 'long'>
` и 
`type(int(int(100e19) + randint(1e18, 1e19-1))) 
<type 'long'>`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, оно даже в int64 не входит, но это же питон - там длинная арифметика при необходимости.

Comment: Автоприведение типов же. Всё, стыдливо уползаю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, какое автоприведение?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> 10**20 + randrange(10**18)
100202623310201395011
```

Comment: Что-то я не верю этому ответу... `randrange` не может слишком мелкое число вернуть?

Comment: @Qwertiy Формула возвращает от `10**20` до `10**20+10**18-1`. Учитывая что автор использует (сломанное) `random.random(18)`, интерпретация, что `'0'*18`  содержит 18 нулей (цифр), вполне подходит и конечная формула в ответе более логична.

Comment: Хм.. А может и так :) Но в других ответах он не говорил, что что-то не так :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '100' + str(random.randint(1e18, 1e19-1))
```

это получается **строка**. Если нужно чтоб было **число**, то добавляем **int**

```
a = int('100' + str(random.randint(1e18, 1e19-1)))
```

Comment: Получится строка, а не число.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, так: `a = int(str(100) + str(random.randint(100000000000000000, 999999999999999999)))`

Comment: random() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @alex замените `random.random(18)`  на `random.randint(100000000000000000, 999999999999999999)`

Comment: А попроще не чего нет?

Comment: @alex проще уже некуда

Comment: Числа преобразуем в строки, конкатенируем, потом обратно в число. Да вроде бы можно проще )

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = int(str(100)+"".join([str(random.randint(1,9)) for i in range(18)]))
>>> a
100613877729784556545
```

Comment: Тут в числе нулей нет.

Comment: С нулями `a = int(str(100)+"".join([str(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(18)]))`